# How to use StringQuery in Elasticsearch Spring Data

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I want to expose flexible REST service which allows client to perform any query. Similar to elasticsearch API:

```
http://localhost:9200/blog/post/_search?q=user:dilbert
```

I found *ElasticsearchTemplate* and it's method *queryForList(StringQuery query, Class clazz)*. It seems to fit for my purpose.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<DynamicEntity> findAllBySearch(@RequestParam("query") String query) {
    return elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(new StringQuery(query), DynamicEntity.class);
}
```

But I don't know how to construct the query. I wasn't able to find documentation on this. I tried to guess it with no success. For example:

```
http://localhost:8080/dynamic/search?query={"query":{"className":"invoice"}}
```

*className* is an attribute of *DynamicEntity*.

I get following error:

```
org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to execute phase [dfs], all shards failed; shardFailures {[feu_3VGkTgKKUziW19mXUQ][dynamic][3]: SearchParseException[[dynamic][3]: from[0],size[10]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10,"query_binary":"eyJxdWVyeSI6eyJjbGFzc05hbWUiOiJpbnZvaWNlIn19"}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[dynamic] No query registered for [query]]; }{[feu_3VGkTgKKUziW19mXUQ][dynamic][4]: SearchParseException[[dynamic][4]: from[0],size[10]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10,"query_binary":"eyJxdWVyeSI6eyJjbGFzc05hbWUiOiJpbnZvaWNlIn19"}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[dynamic] No query registered for [query]]; }{[feu_3VGkTgKKUziW19mXUQ][dynamic][1]: SearchParseException[[dynamic][1]: from[0],size[10]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10,"query_binary":"eyJxdWVyeSI6eyJjbGFzc05hbWUiOiJpbnZvaWNlIn19"}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[dynamic] No query registered for [query]]; }{[feu_3VGkTgKKUziW19mXUQ][dynamic][2]: SearchParseException[[dynamic][2]: from[0],size[10]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10,"query_binary":"eyJxdWVyeSI6eyJjbGFzc05hbWUiOiJpbnZvaWNlIn19"}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[dynamic] No query registered for [query]]; }{[feu_3VGkTgKKUziW19mXUQ][dynamic][0]: SearchParseException[[dynamic][0]: from[0],size[10]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10,"query_binary":"eyJxdWVyeSI6eyJjbGFzc05hbWUiOiJpbnZvaWNlIn19"}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[dynamic] No query registered for [query]]; }
```

Im I using right method? How to construct valid query? I don't want to use any builder classes because the query should be constructed on client in JavaScript.

Comment: Your sample query is not valid (i.e. `No query registered for [query]`), can you try `query={"term":{"className":"invoice"}}` instead (i.e. using `term` instead of `query`)?

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. Do you want to put this as an answer for the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error you posted, your sample query is not valid (i.e. `No query registered for [query]`).

You should use this instead (i.e. using `term` instead of `query`):

```
query={"term":{"className":"invoice"}}
```